Does the presence of a large `found.000` folder on a Windows machine would indicate a dying SSD?
I found a large folder named found.000, I know this is linked to data corruption and bad-sectors but what it means is unclear to me.
Should I change my SSD? Are the bad sectors not used anymore? If I format my SSD would these bad sectors be used again?
If anyone can clarify this, this would be great
SAMSUNG MZ7TE256HMHP-000L7 : 256.0 GB [2/3/1, pd1] - sg
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (03) SAMSUNG MZ7TE256HMHP-000L7
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Model : SAMSUNG MZ7TE256HMHP-000L7
        Firmware : EXT09L6Q
   Serial Number : S1K7NSAF861877
       Disk Size : 256.0 GB (8.4/137.4/256.0/256.0)
     Buffer Size : Unknown
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 500118192
   Rotation Rate : ---- (SSD)
       Interface : Serial ATA
   Major Version : ACS-2
   Minor Version : ATA8-ACS version 4c
   Transfer Mode : SATA/300 | SATA/600
  Power On Hours : 16229 hours
  Power On Count : 3554 count
Wear Level Count : 228
     Temperature : 29 C (84 F)
   Health Status : Good (81 %)
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., NCQ, TRIM, DevSleep
       APM Level : ----
       AAM Level : ----
    Drive Letter : C:

-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
09 _96 _96 __0 000000003F65 Power-on Hours
0C _96 _96 __0 000000000DE2 Power-on Count
AF 100 100 _10 000000000000 Program Fail Count (Chip)
B0 100 100 _10 000000000000 Erase Fail Count (Chip)
B1 _81 _81 __5 0000000000E4 Wear Leveling Count
B2 _85 _85 _10 00000000013E Used Reserved Block Count (Chip)
B3 _91 _91 _10 000000000161 Used Reserved Block Count (Total)
B4 _91 100 _10 000000000FA9 Unused Reserved Block Count (Total)
B5 100 100 _10 000000000000 Program Fail Count (Total)
B6 100 100 _10 000000000000 Erase Fail Count (Total)
B7 _91 __1 _10 000000000161 Runtime Bad Block (Total)
B8 100 100 _97 000000000000 Error Detection
BB __1 __1 __0 00000048516D Uncorrectable Error Count
BE _71 _45 __0 00000000001D Airflow Temperature
C3 199 199 __0 00000048516D ECC Error Rate
C6 _99 _99 __0 000000000002 Off-Line Uncorrectable Error Count
C7 100 100 __0 000000000000 CRC Error Count
E9 199 199 __0 000000000D68 Normalized Media Wear-out
EA 100 100 __0 000000000000 Vendor Specific
EB _99 _99 __0 00000000007B POR Recovery Count
EC _99 _99 __0 0000000000AE Vendor Specific
ED _99 _99 __0 0000000000E4 Vendor Specific
EE _99 _99 __0 000000000161 Vendor Specific

-- IDENTIFY_DEVICE ---------------------------------------------------------
        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
000: 0040 3FFF C837 0010 0000 0000 003F 0000 0000 0000
010: 5331 4B37 4E53 4146 3836 3138 3737 2020 2020 2020
020: 0000 0000 0000 4558 5430 394C 3651 5341 4D53 554E
030: 4720 4D5A 3754 4532 3536 484D 4850 2D30 3030 4C37
040: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 8001 4001 2F00
050: 4000 0200 0200 0007 3FFF 0010 003F FC10 00FB 0101
060: FFFF 0FFF 0000 0007 0003 0078 0078 0078 0078 0F10
070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 001F 870E 00C4 016C 0040
080: 03FC 0039 346B 7D01 4163 3469 BC01 4163 207F 0001
090: 0004 0000 FFFE 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
100: 32B0 1DCF 0000 0000 0000 0008 4000 0000 5002 5388
110: 4458 4D30 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 401E
120: 401C 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0029 0000
130: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
140: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
200: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 003D 0000 0000 4000
210: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000
220: 0000 0000 107F 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
230: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0800 0000 0000 0000 0000
240: 0000 0000 0000 4000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
250: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 77A5

-- SMART_READ_DATA ---------------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 01 00 09 32 00 60 60 65 3F 00 00 00 00 00 0C 32
010: 00 60 60 E2 0D 00 00 00 00 00 AF 32 00 64 64 00
020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 B0 32 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
030: 00 00 B1 13 00 51 51 E4 00 00 00 00 00 00 B2 13
040: 00 55 55 3E 01 00 00 00 00 00 B3 13 00 5B 5B 61
050: 01 00 00 00 00 00 B4 13 00 5B 64 A9 0F 00 00 00
060: 00 00 B5 32 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B6 32
070: 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B7 13 00 5B 01 61
080: 01 00 00 00 00 00 B8 33 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
090: 00 00 BB 32 00 01 01 6D 51 48 00 00 00 00 BE 32
0A0: 00 47 2D 1D 00 00 00 00 00 00 C3 1A 00 C7 C7 6D
0B0: 51 48 00 00 00 00 C6 30 00 63 63 02 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C7 3E 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E9 3A
0D0: 00 C7 C7 68 0D 00 00 00 00 00 EA 12 00 64 64 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 EB 12 00 63 63 7B 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 EC 12 00 63 63 AE 00 00 00 00 00 00 ED 12
100: 00 63 63 E4 00 00 00 00 00 00 EE 12 00 63 63 61
110: 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 53
170: 03 00 01 00 02 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 EC

-- SMART_READ_THRESHOLD ----------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 01 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 00
010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AF 0A 00 00 00 00
020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 B0 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
030: 00 00 B1 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B2 0A
040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B3 0A 00 00 00 00
050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 B4 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
060: 00 00 B5 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B6 0A
070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 B7 0A 00 00 00 00
080: 00 00 00 00 00 00 B8 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
090: 00 00 BB 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BE 00
0A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C3 00 00 00 00 00
0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C6 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C7 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E9 00
0D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 EA 00 00 00 00 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 EB 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 EC 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ED 00
100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 EE 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E3


What's the creation date of the folder? I'm wondering if maybe it's a remnant of having migrated from an HDD to an SSD.

Most SSD manufacturers have software that will tell you the health of the drive. If you add the results of the S.M.A.R.T. test in that software to your question, it may show us something.

All it really means is that something happened and chkdsk needed to run and it found things that had been written without the filesystem being fully updated. Most often it happens after a power failure while writing to disk. It doesn't necessarily mean anything wrong with the SSD, but it could.

@Fractale 1) An SSD has reserved blocks to use when other blocks wear out. The drive itself takes care of that, and there are no bad sectors exposed to the OS (AFAIK). The drive information says "Health Status : Good (81 %)", so it should be good to carry on for a few more years. 2) If you're concerned, and even if you're not, now would be a good time to start making backups. 3) If you find that you need more than 80% of the drive's capacity, getting a larger drive would be useful. Drives work best when they have some free space to work with.
